# How Does Getting the Address of a Class Member Through a Scope Resolution Operator Work When Using a Pointer-to-Member?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, scope, pointer-to-member

When using a pointer-to-member (AKA dot-star or arrow-star) to access a class member, we can use the following syntax:

```
A * pa;
int A::*ptm2 = &A::n;
std::cout << "pa->*ptm: " << pa->*ptm << '\n';
```

My question is how does the `&A::n` statement work?

In the above example `n` is a variable.  If instead of a member variable, `n` was a function (and we defined a pointer-to-a-member-function instead of a pointer-to-a-member), I might reason that since a class's functions can be effectively static (see Nemo's comment), we could find a class's function's address via `&A::some_function`.  But how can we get the address of a non-static class member through a class scope resolution?  This is even more confusing when I print the value of `&A::n` because the output is merely `1`.

Comment: For member variables, it's the offset from the beginning of the object instance. `->*` is then roughly equivalent to a mere addition of both its LHS (instance) and RHS (offset) parts.

Comment: @syam That's what I thought. But if I print `&A::member_variable` for multiple member variables, I get `1` for all of them.

Comment: A class's functions are not necessarily "effectively static"; consider virtual functions, multiple inheritance, etc... The internal representation for "pointer to member" can get very complicated. Some implementations use up to 16 bytes for them (see, e.g., http://lazarenko.me/2013/04/28/cc-pointers-to-member-functions/)

Comment: @user2141130 That's because when you try to print it, it doesn't print the offset itself but gets converted to something else (a boolean I think, but I can't be arsed to check that right now -- anyway you get the idea, you're not printing what you think).

Comment: @Nemo Good point, thank you. I made a small edit to avoid giving someone my bad idea!

Comment: @user2141130 In fact the check is easy to do, it's indeed converted to a boolean: `cout << boolalpha << &Class::member;` will output `true` instead of `1`. QED ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a pointer to member data, it isn't bounded to any particular instance. If you want to know the address of a data member for a given instance you need to take the address of the result after doing `.*` or `->*`. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
  int n;
};

int main()
{
  A a  = {42};
  A aa = {55};
  int A::*ptm = &A::n;
  printf("a.*ptm: %p\n", (void *)&(a.*ptm));
  printf("aa.*ptm: %p\n", (void *)&(aa.*ptm));
}
```

prints as one possible output:

```
a.*ptm: 0xbfbe268c
aa.*ptm: 0xbfbe2688
```