# Accessing the address of a member data through qualified name yields error

Tags: c++, memory-address

As we know, a direct or indirect base class's of a derived class `public` and `protected` members are available in that derived one.

So I have this example:

```
struct Foo{int x_ = 10;};
struct Bar : Foo{};
struct FooBar : Bar{
    void f()const{
        std::cout << &x_ << " : " << x_ << '\n';
        std::cout << &Foo::x_ << " : " << Foo::x_ << '\n';
        std::cout << &Bar::x_ << " : " << Bar::x_ << '\n';
        std::cout << &FooBar::x_ << " : " << FooBar::x_ << '\n';
    }
};



int main(){
    FooBar fb{};
    fb.f();
}
```

- When I compile and run the program I get the output:

  ```
    0x7ffc2f7ca878 : 10
    1 : 10
    1 : 10
    1 : 10
  ```

So why accessing the address of the member data `A::x_` through a fully-qualified names yields an "Invalid" address? but accessing it directly (unqualified lookup) is OK.

- Is my program in Undefined Behavior?
- I've compiled my program using GCC and CLANG.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly which of the outputs you're confused by? Also, what is `A::x_`?

Comment: @cigien Why I get 1 : 1 from &Foo::x_ , &Bar::x_ and &Bar::x_?

Comment: Unrelated, should the second `&Foo::x_` in `std::cout << &Foo::x_ << " : " << &Foo::x_ << '\n';` be `Foo::x_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, most likely you did not intend to repeat the `&` operator in each `std::cout` statement, so I've removed each repeated instance,  to print the value of a member rather than its address.

Now watch this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{int x_ = 10;};
struct Bar : Foo{};
struct FooBar : Bar
{
  void f()const
  {
    std::cout << &x_ << " : " << x_ << '\n';
    std::cout << &(Foo::x_) << " : " << Foo::x_ << '\n';
    std::cout << &(Bar::x_) << " : " << Bar::x_ << '\n';
    std::cout << &(FooBar::x_) << " : " << FooBar::x_ << '\n';
  }
};

int main(){
  FooBar fb{};
  fb.f();
}
```

Output:

> 0x7fffe136c594 : 10
> 0x7fffe136c594 : 10
> 0x7fffe136c594 : 10
> 0x7fffe136c594 : 10

Everything works just fine! What  I changed was to enclose expressions like `Foo::x_` in parenthesis. Why? Because `&Foo::x_`  uses the **Built-in address-of operator**, see [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) in cppreference.com. Its value is a **pointer to data member**, which is NOT an ordinary pointer, as it needs to be bound to an object in order to return an address. See also [Similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756025/how-does-getting-the-address-of-a-class-member-through-a-scope-resolution-operat) for additional explanation.

**EDIT**

You might wonder why `std::cout` displays `1` for your pointer-to-member pointers. Its because of the implicit conversion to `bool`:

> Boolean conversions
> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to a prvalue of type bool.

[Quotation source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

The converted value is, of course, `true`, because your pointers are valid ones, and only `nullptr` (and 0) is converted to `false`. By other rule, `true` is converted to 1. Q.E.D.

Comment: Yes sure! it was a mistake using the reference operator twice there.

Comment: I do really appreciate it! It is clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Does this have a relation with operator precedence? the scope operator has a higher precedence than the reference operator. so you used the parenthesis to change the precedence? right?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. I guess `& ::` is a separate operator and parsing it takes precedence before `::`. However,   I've never seen  `& ::` in C++ operator lists nor on operator precedence lists. If you write `++x`, the syntax says this is a single `++` operator, not two `+` operators. Here it must be the same. The syntax wins over operator precedence table.

Comment: Also, it is interesting to see how pointers-to-data-members are implemented.  In gcc they seem to be simply the offsets into the structure members they point at, so the compiler has an easy task in applying them to objects: take the address of the object and increase it by this offset.

Comment: I imagine it like this. If the compiler parses `&X`, it checks if `X` is an object or addressable l-value. If so, it ends parsing this token, and assumes `&` is the address-of operator. Otherwise it checks if `X` represents class or struct name. If yes, it goes into the  "address-of-member" mode and expects `::` followed by a member of `X`. Thus, `&Bar::x_` would form a single parsing token. In contast, in  `&(Bar::x_)` there are two tokens, one of them being `(Bar::x_)` and the other - `&` on the result of the first.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my program in Undefined Behavior?

No. The behaviour is well defined.

> So why accessing the address of the member data A::x_ through a fully-qualified names yields an "Invalid" address?

You aren't using fully-qualified names. A fully qualified name always begins from the global namespace. For example, `::Foo::x_` would be a fully qualified name, while `Foo::x_` it not.

You also aren't "accessing" the members (except when you insert `x_`). When you apply the unary operator `&` on a member name, the result is a pointer to data member. In the case of `&Foo::x_`, the type would be a `int Foo::*` i.e. pointer to member of `Foo` of type `int`.

Furthermore, 1 isn't necessarily "invalid" address, but what you are observing isn't an address at all. Character streams do not have a stream insertion operator that accepts a pointer to data member. They do however have an overload that accepts a bool and all pointers to data members are implicitly convertible to bool, and thus such overload is a valid candidate for overload resolution.

Since the pointer to data member in question isn't null, the converted value is true. When true is inserted to a character stream, the output is 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for such useful explanation.